# Mysql 8.0: Query becomes intractable if requesting JSON column from a LEFT JOINed table

Tags: mysql

I have a problem regarding a query I built on my database, and I am at a loss on why this happens:

I have tables A and B, where A contains its id and a datetime column, while B has a foreign key linked to `A.id`, one text and one JSON column containing arrays.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT A.datetime,
 B.text_col,
 B.json_col
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id
WHERE A.datetime BETWEEN "2021-12-07 09:55:14" AND "2021-12-08 09:55:14"
```

This query takes forever (I haven't yet managed to see it completed).

But simply removing the `B.json_col` from `SELECT` makes the query super fast, so does using an `INNER JOIN` rather than a `LEFT JOIN`.

Given the characteristics of the tables, the quantity of data returned by each query should not be really different: only ~5% of rows from A should not have at least one corresponding B row, and the JSON field is relatively small (2 or 3 elements of 100 characters each).

It almost seems like a bug to me, but I wanted to check if I wasn't missing something obvious (or not so obvious) regarding JSON fields in Mysql that would prevent me from getting a JSON field from a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: pls try this and post the EXPLAIN of your 2 querys amd my query : **SELECT C.datetime,
 B.text_col,
 B.json_col
FROM ( SELECT tmp.id, tmp.datetime FROM A AS tmp WHERE tmp.datetime BETWEEN "2021-12-07 09:55:14" AND "2021-12-08 09:55:14" ) AS C
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = C.id;
**

Comment: Mmh, I am not sure what you expected, but your request, as well as mine with or without the  json field have the exact same EXPLAIN. In both cases, they seem to use `where` instead of the index, but that seems to not be the source of the problem since it works fine as long as I do not request the JSON field

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE for both tables. Give tables statistic (approx. rows amount, approx. average `a_id` amount per value, approx. rows amount to be returned by your query). Show EXPLAIN for both queries mentioned. Show an example of tables values (2-3 rows per table).